# How to display an inter object in the readline command in r?

Tags: r

I have declared an integer object called "teamStrength" and want to call it in the readline command. I know this is pretty much how to do it in Java but how do I display the object? "teamStrength" is supposed to change so I can't just display the actual number.

```
teamStrength <- mean(teams$Fifa.Rating, trim = 0.5)
CONTINUE <- readline(prompt = 'Your team strength is ' + teamStrength + 
                             'Type yes if you want to continue. Type no if 
                              you want to rechoose. ')
```

Comment: In R we combined characters (most other languages say strings) with `paste()`. It will coerce `teamStrength` to a character automatically.

Comment: as @joran said, paste your elements, like `prompt = paste(element1, element2, ...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prompt string should be concatenated with `paste()`, rather than plus signs. Your code should be something like this:

```
teamStrength <- mean(teams$Fifa.Rating, trim = 0.5)
CONTINUE <- readline(prompt = paste('Your team strength is ', 
                     teamStrength, 'Type yes if you want to continue. 
                     Type no if you want to rechoose. '))
```

Comment: You forgot to remove the `+` signs! ;)